# Coaxing DSolve: Second-order PDE

Tags: differential-equations, approximation

I am trying to solve the following PDE for a function $\Gamma(q, r)$, which I have derived in the context of an optimal control problem:
$$
 2 (\gamma -1) \rho ^{\frac{\gamma }{\gamma -1}} \left(q^{\frac{\gamma }{\gamma -1}}+r^{\frac{\gamma }{\gamma -1}}\right) \Gamma (q,r)^{\frac{\gamma }{\gamma -1}}+2 (\beta -\gamma  \rho ) \Gamma (q,r)-r \left(2 \mu  \Gamma ^{(0,1)}(q,r)+r \sigma ^2 \Gamma ^{(0,2)}(q,r)\right)-q \left(2 \nu  \Gamma ^{(1,0)}(q,r)+q \tau ^2 \Gamma ^{(2,0)}(q,r)\right)=0
$$

All of the lowercase Greek symbols are constants. This is *almost* a 2D Cauchy-Euler equation, but with an additional non-linear term (that has been giving me a headache).

`DSolve` is able to solve this system in the limit $\sigma = 0 = \tau$

```
pdeGamma=(2 (\[Beta]-\[Gamma] \[Rho]) \[CapitalGamma][q,r]+2 (q^(\[Gamma]/(-1+\[Gamma]))+r^(\[Gamma]/(-1+\[Gamma]))) (-1+\[Gamma]) \[Rho]^(\[Gamma]/(-1+\[Gamma])) \[CapitalGamma][q,r]^(\[Gamma]/(-1+\[Gamma]))-r (2 \[Mu] (\[CapitalGamma]^(0,1))[q,r]+r \[Sigma]^2 (\[CapitalGamma]^(0,2))[q,r])-q (2 \[Nu] (\[CapitalGamma]^(1,0))[q,r]+q \[Tau]^2 (\[CapitalGamma]^(2,0))[q,r]))==0

gammaDetSol = DSolve[
  pdeGamma /. {\[Sigma] -> 0, \[Tau] -> 0},
  \[CapitalGamma],
  {q, r}
  ]
```

Is there any way to coax `DSolve` to solve this for the full problem by specifying an initial guess or simplifying the notation or something else? I have tried guessing solutions of a form similar to the deterministic case for two days now, but to no avail. Approximate or power series solutions are welcome--anything to help build intuition.

*PS.* Depending on the feedback I receive, I am open to start thinking about numerical solutions as well. In this case, I can provide the boundary conditions at $q \to \infty$ and $r \to \infty$.